# Como consumir dados da API RESTFul?

Tags: html5, laravel-5, bootstrap-3, restful

Assisti algumas vídeo aulas sobre RESTFul e fiz um em Laravel 5.4. Agora gostaria de usar um template que tenho feito em HTML5 + Bootstrap 3 para consumir esses dados, por onde eu começo? O que eu preciso fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você tem o serviço rodando que te retorna os dados, você precisa consumir eles de alguma forma, podes fazer isso através da linguagem que está utilizando (*PHP*) ou via *JavaScript* (fazendo requisições ajax) por exemplo.